# In the expression $3x$, what is the $3$?

Tags: terminology, definition

So this is quite a simple question. I KNOW I learnt this before, but can't for the life of me figure out or find anywhere that refers to the definition I'm looking for. Look at the expression
$$
3x
$$
In this expression, what is the $3$ in this context? The $3$ 'prefixes' the $x$, but I don't believe that it is called a prefix of $x$.

Comment: What is $x$...?

Comment: It could be "scalar" if used in contex of Algebra.

Comment: $x$ is a variable, like how you find $x^2$

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife that jogged my memory, exactly what I'm looking for. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: 3 could also be a "coefficient".

Comment: If there is an (commutative) addition for the entities $x$ then $3x$ is normally defined as $3x := x+x+x$

Comment: $3x$ is defined as $3\cdot x$; now read it out loud: "Three times $x$."

Comment: The *definition* of $3$ is surely $1+1+1$, but in a formula like this it is often *called* a coefficient (or **the** coefficient of $x^1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the algebraic structure you have in mind and what $3x$ represents.

- If $3x$ represents the scalar multiplication of $3$ and $x$, then $3$ is a **scalar** and $x$ is a **vector**. But sometimes, the scalars are called **coefficients**, especially when they appear in linear combinations.
- The expression $3x$ could also represent the vector addition of $3$ and $x$ (for example, when the structure you have in mind is the vector space of positive-real numbers with usual multiplication and exponentiation), or it could be the inner product of $3$ and $x$ (in a one-dimensional inner-product space). In both cases, $3$ and $x$ are **vectors**.
- A more general term would simply be **element**. For example, if you have a group structue, and $3x$ represents the combination of $3$ and $x$ using the group operation, then $3$ and $x$ are **elements** of the group.

Answer (score 3):

You call it the *coefficient* of $x$, and it *multiplies* $x$.

You can also consider that $3$ is the *multiplier* of the *multiplicand* $x$, but this is more appropriate in symmetrical situations (like $ab$).

Answer (score 1):

A "scalar" in contex of Algebra.
Could be  also a "coefficient".